# Theoretical speedup from sample number in path tracing algorithm

Tags: pathtracing, performance, importance-sampling, supersampling

Suppose, in a Kajiya style path tracing algorithm, I have `100x100` pixels, and I am using `32 samples per pixel`. So, the total number of samples `is 320000`.

Now, if I render the same scene with `25x25` pixels (I meant, then upscale it to `100x100` resolution), and use `8 samples per pixel`, the total samples are `5000`.

From these two, can I theoretically estimate that my new path tracing can be `(320000/5000) = 64 times` faster?

How to calculate the theoretical performance gain in path tracing? Would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to think that the time to trace a ray and evaluate the illumination model will vary significantly between the two cases at nearby  locations (even using acceleration techniques that exploit locality), nor is there a reason to think that upscaling will represent a significant fraction of the workload.

So the ratio of the numbers of rays traced should be an excellent estimate of the speedup.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand it. You meant my estimation is not valid? How to calculate (theoretically) before and after ray numbers to find the ratio? Can you suggest any document?

Comment: @bim: what don't you understand ? The is no need of a document for such a triviality.

Comment: Daous, actually this has significance to me.

Comment: @bim To summarize this answer, yes, your theoretical estimate of using just the ratio of ray counts, is a good estimate.